# Grover algorithm when element not present in the array/database

Tags: quantum-computing

I've been reading about the Grover algorithm for finding elements in an unstructured database by the means of quantum computing, and even done some exercises.

What I don't understand (and can't find anywhere) is what is supposed to happen if the element is NOT present in the database. The oracle would never flip any qubit, and then I don't know what would happen with the inversion about the mean operator. Would the algorithm keep iterating forever?

Comment: Grover's algorithm won't loop forever, because it always performs $O(\sqrt{N})$ iterations.

Comment: That's right, I misunderstood the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic version of Grover's algorithm has a fixed number of iterations and assumes there is one marked item. If there is no marked item instead of one marked item, you will do those iterations but then get a random answer.

[As mentioned in the wikipedia article on Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm#Extension_to_space_with_multiple_targets), the algorithm can be extended to work when there are an unknown number of marked items while still running in $O(\sqrt{N})$ time. There's just more details to work out.